# pgfplot : fine tuning of scale on axis

Tags: pgfplots, axis

I try to have the next scale on x-axis :
1cm for 4 graduations, labeled 4 by 4 every cm.

with `max space between ticks=23`, its 2 by 2.

with `max space between ticks=24`, its 5 by 5.

Any other idea ?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest, %footnotesize
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend style={font=\small},
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    every axis/.style={pin distance=1ex},
    major grid style={gray,opacity=.90},
    %xlabel near ticks
    %   
    }   %%%% fin pgfplotsset


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis x line = center,   % bottom,
    axis y line = left,     % center, si on veut que les axes se coupe a (0,0)
    xmin=0, xmax=64,        % intervalle sur l'axe des abscisses
    ymin=-90, ymax=10,      % intervalle sur l'axe des ordonnee
    scale only axis=true,   % on en tient pas compte de ce qui est autour des
                            % axes pour la mise a l'echelle
    x=.25cm, y=.2cm,        % echelle sur chaque axe
    xmajorgrids,            % affiche la grille principale verticale
    ymajorgrids,            % affiche la grille principale horizontale
    xminorgrids,            % affiche la grille secondaire verticale
    yminorgrids,            % affiche la grille secondaire horizontale
    minor x tick num=3,     % 4 lignes de grille secondaire par unite
    minor y tick num=4,     % 4 lignes de grille secondaire par unite
        % permet d'augmenter ou de diminuer le nombre de de labels sur les axes.
        % Plus le nombre est grand moins il y a de labels
    max space between ticks=23,
    %try min ticks=3,       % nombre minimum de labels (peut servir ...)
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you after `xtick distance=4,ytick distance=4`?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I am ! Only for x. I didn't know this command. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but in case I do. You can force the distance between ticks with `xtick distance`, and similarly for y. Alternatively, set the tick locations explicitly, with `xtick={0,4,...,64}`, and similarly for y.

Also, if you explicitly want 1cm for every 4 axis units, along both x and y, set the width and height accordingly. You have 64/100 units along x/y, so set `width`/`height` to 16cm/25cm.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{%
    compat=newest, %footnotesize
    tick label style={font=\footnotesize},
    label style={font=\small},
    legend style={font=\small},
    axis x line = center,
    axis y line = center,
    every axis/.style={pin distance=1ex},
    major grid style={gray,opacity=.90},
    %xlabel near ticks
    %   
    }   %%%% fin pgfplotsset


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    axis x line = center,   % bottom,
    axis y line = left,     % center, si on veut que les axes se coupe a (0,0)
    xmin=0, xmax=64,        % intervalle sur l'axe des abscisses
    ymin=-90, ymax=10,      % intervalle sur l'axe des ordonnee
    scale only axis=true,   % on en tient pas compte de ce qui est autour des
                            % axes pour la mise a l'echelle
    width=16cm, % because (xmax-xmin)/4=16
    height=25cm, % because (ymax-ymin)/4=25
    xmajorgrids,            % affiche la grille principale verticale
    ymajorgrids,            % affiche la grille principale horizontale
    xminorgrids,            % affiche la grille secondaire verticale
    yminorgrids,            % affiche la grille secondaire horizontale
    minor x tick num=3,     % 4 lignes de grille secondaire par unite
    minor y tick num=3,     % 4 lignes de grille secondaire par unite
        % permet d'augmenter ou de diminuer le nombre de de labels sur les axes.
        % Plus le nombre est grand moins il y a de labels
    xtick distance=4,
    ytick distance=4,
    % or alternatively, set the tick locations explicitly
    %xtick={0,4,...,64},
    %ytick={-90,-86,...,10} 
    ]

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```